# El contenido de la pagina esta corrido a la izquierda y hay una margen blanco a la derecha y sale una barra inferior

Tags: bootstrap

Un gran saludo para todos.

Apenas inicio y he tenido varias dificultades, entre esas que se ha corrido el contenido de la pagina a un lado de tal forma que sale con una barra inferior como si hubiera más contenido en los extremos, normalmente sale solo una barra vertical por que hay más contenido abajo, pero en esta oportunidad me sale esa barra abajo, aún estoy haciendo el sitio web, sin embargo les muestro una imagen de como debería ser y otra de lo que me sucede.

Muchas Gracias.
[image: Estoy tratando me quede así][image: Y creo que el contenido se ha corrido y me sale esa barra inferior]

```css
.nosotros{
background: no-repeat center center; 
-webkit-background-size: 100% 100%;
-moz-background-size: 100% 100%;
-o-background-size: 100% 100%;
background-size: 100% 100%;
height: 600px;
}

.texto-nosotros {
 margin-top: 200px;
}

.caja-nosotros {
   width: 100%;
    height:inherit;    
    padding: 50px;
    border: 1px solid black;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.equipo-trabajo {
 margin-top: 100px;
 margin-bottom: 100px;
}
```

```html
<!-- HEADER -->
<body>
<header>
  <div class="container">
      <img class="center-block logo" src="imagenes/Logo.png">
  </div>
</header>


<!-- MENU -->
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#myNavbar">
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> 
        </button>
    <a class="navbar-header" href="#"><img class="visible-xs" src="imagenes/logo-menu.png"></a>
  </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="myNavbar">
        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
          <li><a href="index.html">INICIO</a></li>
          <li><a href="nosotros.html">NOSOTROS</a></li>
          <li><a href="servicios.html">SERVICIOS</a></li> 
          <li><a href="contacto.html">CONTACTO</a></li> 
        </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav> 


  

<div class="row">
  <div class="container">
     <video controls poster="imagenes/v-nosotros.jpg" src="Videos/v_nosotros.mp4"/>Your browser does not support the video tag.</video>
  </div>
</div>
  

<section class="nosotros" style="background-image: url(imagenes/parallax.png); background-size: 100%;">
    

    <div class="col-xs-10 col-md-10-offset-2">
      <div class="texto-nosotros">
            <h1 class="text-center"><b>ACERCA DE</b> “JOSÉ MIGUEL, ARTE Y BELLEZA”</h1><br>

        <div class="caja-nosotros">
            <p>Durante más de ....en la que se ofrecen productos y servicios de gran calidad a precios apropiados.</p>
        </div>

      </div>
      </div>
   </div>
</section>


 
<div class="container">
<div class="equipo-trabajo">
  
    <div class="row">
      <h1 class="text-center"><b>EQUIPO</b> DE TRABAJO</h1><br><br>

        <div class="col-md-2"></div>
        <div class="col-sm-3 "><img class="img-responsive" src="imagenes/normal/josemiguel.png"><br><br><h4 style="text-align:center"><b>José</b></br>Estilista Integral</h4></div>

        <div class="col-sm-3"><img class="img-responsive" src="imagenes/normal/luciajaimes.png"><br><br><h4 style="text-align:center"><b>Lucia</b></br>Estilista Integral</h4></div>
        
        <div class="col-sm-3 "><img class="img-responsive" src="imagenes/normal/nataliatorres.png"><br><br><h4 style="text-align:center"><b>Natalia</b></br>Estilista Integral</h4></div>
        <div class="col-md-2"></div>

    </div>
</div>
</div>
 
<!-- FOOTER -->  
<footer>
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-left">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">CONTACTO:</h6>
            <h6 class="text-muted">
            Carrera 8h No. 166-71 Local 2<br>
            Santa Cruz de la Ronda.<br>
            Teléfonos: 3115988953 – 3112641818.<br>
            </h6>
        </div>

        <div class="col-xs-12 col-md-6 text-right">
            <h6 class="text-muted lead">ENCUENTRANOS EN LAS REDES</h6>
            <div class="redes-footer">
              <a href="https://www.facebook.com/"><img src="imagenes/facebook-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://twitter.com/"><img src="imagenes/twitter-2.png"></a>
              <a href="https://www.youtube.com/"><img src="imagenes/youtube-2.png"></a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row"> 

        <div class="col-md-12 text-right">
            <p class="text-muted small">José Miguel, arte y belleza @2016.<br> Todos los derechos reservados.</p>
        </div>
        
    </div>

    </div>
  </div>  
</div>
</footer>


  
    <script src="js/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No sabría decirte específicamente el error, estaría bueno inspeccionarlo con la consola. En fin, te puedo dar una idea que no soluciona realmente el problema pero puede ayudarte. Agrega este css:

```
body, html {
    width: 100%;
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

Esto lo que hace es evitar que aparezca la barra de scroll horizontal.
Ahora el asunto del contenido desplazado, si es en todo el sitio en general puedo corregirlo (parche) agregando un **margin-left=-N°px** al body mismo, sino a la caja con el problema en cuestión.